# On function Call getting error as Variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table which i am creating with Json Data.I have Three buttons inside my form  `save` ,`View` and `Edit` edit is initially hidden on clicking on view it shows up.

so on clicking view i am calling a function which is doing some work, then again i am clicking on edit and i am calling my `addTable(tableData)` function it says un defined

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.loader').show();
  $('.overlay').show();

  $.ajax({

    url: "CategoryOlWiseFilter",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function(tableData) {
      addTable(tableData);
      $('.loader').hide();
      $('.overlay').hide();
      $("#divHide").show();
    }
  });
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    if (confirm("Want to clear?")) {
      $('.dataReset').val(0);
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#CategoryName").on("change", function() {
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    console.log(selectedOption);

    var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

    if (selectedOption === "All") {

      for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
        itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    } else {

      for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
        itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
      }

      var selectedItemRows = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category='" + selectedOption + "']");

      for (var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++) {
        selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
  });
});

var itemsQuantiry = [];

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  var colNum = col.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {

      var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        if (itemsQuantiry[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry[i]);
        } else {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", "0");
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {
        if (tableData[i]["Item Code"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Code");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]["Item Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }

        if (tableData[i]["Category Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Category_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1) tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }

  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}

function editData() {
  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#view').show();
  $('#edit').hide();
  addTable(tableData); // here i am getting the error

}
$(".dataReset").on("change", function(e) {
  itemsQuantiry[$(this).attr('index')] = e.target.value;
});
$("#save").click(function() {
  var outlet = $('#outlet');
  if (outlet.val() === 'Select Outlet') {
    alert("Please Select An Outlet!");
    $('#outlet').focus();
    return false;
  } else return;
});

function viewData() {
  var quantityFields = document.getElementsByClassName("dataReset");
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityFields.length; i++) {
    if (quantityFields[i].value != 0) {
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#view').hide();
  $('#edit').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <div class="col-lg-4  brder">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Outlet Name</h5>
        <select class="test" id="outlet" name="outlet">
          <option>Select Outlet</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Outlet Code</h5>
        <select class="test" id="outletCode" name="outletCode">
          <option>Outlet Code</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>

      <button type="button" id="view" class="commonButton" onclick="viewData()">
     <i class="fas fa-eye"></i> View
    </button>
      <button id="edit" type="button" class="commonButton" onclick="editData()" style="display: none">
     <i class="far fa-edit"></i>edit
    </button>


    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

initially when page loads i am making an ajax call and populating the table in side success function i am calling `addTable(tableData)` function

- then user clicks on `view` and again clicks on `edit` it shows error as `ReferenceError: tableData is not defined` as you can see in my code i have commented that line
- I think it is not able to find `tableData`
- So where should i put my `editdata` function
- I think i am misplacing the code pattern

**On clicking of edit you can see it shows the error on console**

The JSON i am getting from back-end.value of `tableData`

```
[{"Item Code":"1978","Item Name":"Alu Chat-S","Category Name":"Chats"},{"Item Code":"1979","Item Name":"Dahi Alu Chat-S","Category Name":"Chats"},{"Item Code":"1980","Item Name":"Samosa-S","Category Name":"Chats"},{"Item Code":"1981","Item Name":"SamosaChat-S","Category Name":"Chats"},{"Item Code":"1982","Item Name":"Dahi Samosa Chats-S","Category Name":"regular"},{"Item Code":"1983","Item Name":"Garam Samosa Chats-S","Category Name":"regular"},{"Item Code":"1984","Item Name":"Kachori Chats-S","Category Name":"regular"},{"Item Code":"1985","Item Name":"Garam Kachori Chat-S","Category Name":"regular"},{"Item Code":"1986","Item Name":"Dahi Kachori Chat-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1987","Item Name":"Dai Raj Kachori-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1988","Item Name":"Baby Kachori Chat-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1989","Item Name":"Dahi Baby Kachori-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1990","Item Name":"Anar Bhalla-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1991","Item Name":"Dahi Bhalla-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1992","Item Name":"Jhal Muri-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1993","Item Name":"Chat Platter-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1994","Item Name":"Dahi Papdi Chat-S","Category Name":"GIFT PACK"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <div class="col-lg-4  brder">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Outlet Name</h5>
        <select class="test" id="outlet" name="outlet">
          <option>Select Outlet</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Outlet Code</h5>
        <select class="test" id="outletCode" name="outletCode">
          <option>Outlet Code</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>

      <button type="button" id="view" class="commonButton" onclick="viewData()">
     <i class="fas fa-eye"></i> View
    </button>
      <button id="edit" type="button" class="commonButton" onclick="editData()" style="display: none">
     <i class="far fa-edit"></i>edit
    </button>


    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var tableData = [{"Item Code":"1978","Item Name":"Alu Chat-S","Category Name":"Chats"},{"Item Code":"1979","Item Name":"Dahi Alu Chat-S","Category Name":"Chats"},{"Item Code":"1980","Item Name":"Samosa-S","Category Name":"Chats"},{"Item Code":"1981","Item Name":"SamosaChat-S","Category Name":"Chats"},{"Item Code":"1982","Item Name":"Dahi Samosa Chats-S","Category Name":"regular"},{"Item Code":"1983","Item Name":"Garam Samosa Chats-S","Category Name":"regular"},{"Item Code":"1984","Item Name":"Kachori Chats-S","Category Name":"regular"},{"Item Code":"1985","Item Name":"Garam Kachori Chat-S","Category Name":"regular"},{"Item Code":"1986","Item Name":"Dahi Kachori Chat-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1987","Item Name":"Dai Raj Kachori-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1988","Item Name":"Baby Kachori Chat-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1989","Item Name":"Dahi Baby Kachori-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1990","Item Name":"Anar Bhalla-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1991","Item Name":"Dahi Bhalla-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1992","Item Name":"Jhal Muri-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1993","Item Name":"Chat Platter-S","Category Name":"fastfood"},{"Item Code":"1994","Item Name":"Dahi Papdi Chat-S","Category Name":"GIFT PACK"}];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.loader').show();
  $('.overlay').show();
 
  $.ajax({

    url: "CategoryOlWiseFilter",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function(data) {
    tableData = data;
    console.log(tableData);
      addTable(tableData);
      $('.loader').hide();
      $('.overlay').hide();
      $("#divHide").show();
    }
  });
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    if (confirm("Want to clear?")) {
      $('.dataReset').val(0);
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#CategoryName").on("change", function() {
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    console.log(selectedOption);

    var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

    if (selectedOption === "All") {

      for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
        itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    } else {

      for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
        itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
      }

      var selectedItemRows = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category='" + selectedOption + "']");

      for (var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++) {
        selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
  });
});

var itemsQuantiry = [];

function addTable(tableData) {
console.log(1);
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  var colNum = col.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {

      var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        if (itemsQuantiry[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry[i]);
        } else {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", "0");
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {
        if (tableData[i]["Item Code"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Code");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]["Item Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }

        if (tableData[i]["Category Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Category_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1) tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }

  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}

function editData() {
  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#view').show();
  $('#edit').hide();
  if (typeof tableData != 'undefined' && tableData != '') {
  alert('before edit');
   addTable(tableData);
  }// here i am getting the error

}
$(".dataReset").on("change", function(e) {
  itemsQuantiry[$(this).attr('index')] = e.target.value;
});
$("#save").click(function() {
  var outlet = $('#outlet');
  if (outlet.val() === 'Select Outlet') {
    alert("Please Select An Outlet!");
    $('#outlet').focus();
    return false;
  } else return;
});

function viewData() {
  var quantityFields = document.getElementsByClassName("dataReset");
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityFields.length; i++) {
    if (quantityFields[i].value != 0) {
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#view').hide();
  $('#edit').show();
}
</script>
</html>
```

Yes tableData is not defined and you are using it from out of scope.For this you need to declared it inside document ready and assign success response in that.For avoiding error you have to implement undefined and not empty check.Please see below code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.loader').show();
 $('.overlay').show();
 var tableData = '';
```

After success call assign value to tableData you should also handle failure response as your api returning 404.

```
success: function(data) {
tableData = data;
addTable(tableData);
```

Inside editData function handle this

```
function editData() {
 $('#CategoryName').val('All');
 $('#view').show();
 $('#edit').hide();
 if (typeof tableData != 'undefined' && tableData != '') {
  addTable(tableData);
 }// here i am getting the error
```

Comment: hey when i am clicking edit i am calling my addTable(tableData) again but its not showing up

Comment: Yes its same issue just define tableData as mentioned above and check your response is success or failure.

Comment: you are defining table data inside `$(document).ready(function() {}` so should i define editData inside that also?

Comment: hey you there ?

Comment: No no need to define inside edit data just handle the check of not undefined and not empty.

Comment: i tried your approach i defined tableData inside like `$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.loader').show();
   $('.overlay').show();
   var tableData="";`   and editdata outside function `editData() {
   $('#CategoryName').val('All');
   $('#view').show();
   $('#edit').hide();  
   if (typeof tableData != 'undefined' && tableData != '') {
     addTable(tableData);
   }
   
  }`  but when i am clicking on edit the addTable is not calling, why

Comment: yes because tableData not set its still empty.You have put console.log(tableData) inside your ajax success call.As i have checked you ajax getting failed.So it will not execute inside ajax success call thats why tableData will be empty and addTable method will not call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187546/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-singh).

Answer (score 1):

`editdata` function has not access to `tableData` and that's why it makes error.

You can define `tableData` variable in outer scope and after ajax call assign value to that:

```
var tableData;
$(document).ready(function() {
...
success: function(tableDataResponse) {
      tableData = tableDataResponse;  // assign value to our global variable
      addTable(tableData);
...
```

Now `editData` has access to `tableData`.

Hope to help.

Comment: Also you can define `tableData` variable inside of `$(document).ready(function() {})` but if you define `editData` in that scope too.

Comment: hey it shows error as `tableData is undefined` in my addTable(tabledata) code

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would be of course undefined as you did not declare variable tableData inside edit function

You can get data of table by table id for reference check this [Get data of table by table id](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp)

Now you need to modify edit function like this

```
function editData() {
   var tableData = document.getElementById("myTable").rows
   $('#CategoryName').val('All');
   $('#view').show();
   $('#edit').hide();
   addTable(tableData); // here i am getting the error

}
```

Let me know if id did not work or you need more help

Comment: hey getting error as `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object` at line no 55 in my snippet of js on clicking on edit....i am replacing `myTable` with my table id i.e `HourlysalesSummary`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is tableData falls in the scope of the Ajax call with line:

```
success: function(tableData) {
```

You can make it available but assigning it to a variable outside this scope, to the same scope as editData eg:

```
var returned_data;
$(document).ready(function() {
```

And then updating your success function in your ajax:

```
 success: function(tableData) {
      addTable(tableData);
      returned_data = tableData;
```

It can then be called in in editData

```
function editData() {
  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#view').show();
  $('#edit').hide();
  addTable(returned_data); // here i am getting the error

}
```

Comment: `editData` is defined in outer scope so if `returned_data` is defined in `$(document).ready` callback function, it cannot be accessed again.

Comment: hey not getting the result

Comment: What result? You need to be more specific with what is not working and where